# Are signature-changing decorators a bad pattern?

Tags: python

I have a number of functions of the form:

```
def parse_file_1(file_name)
    # do something generic
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            # do some generic things with line
            # do some things specific to parse_file_1 with line
```

To avoid repeating lots of that code, I rewrote it using a decorator:

```
def parse_file(parse_function):
     def _parse_file(file_name):
         # do something generic
         with open(file_name) as f:
             for line in f:
                 # do some generic things with line
                 parse_function(line)
     return _parse_file

@parse_file
def parse_file_1(line):
    # do some things specific to parse_file_1 with line
```

And this works completely fine - the two versions are functionally identical, as intended, and it's very easy to write new functions of this form without any copy-and-paste of the generic code.

However, the decorator `parse_file` changes the signature of `parse_file_1`, which confuses PyCharm (it thinks `parse_file_1` has signature `(line)` rather than `(file_name)`), and in general makes it hard to determine the signature of `parse_file_1`.

How bad a practice is this, and (if it is bad) what good alternatives are there (ideally that don't require much repeated code)? Alternatively, a way to make PyCharm aware of `parse_file_1`'s true signature would remove the biggest issue I have with the current situation.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use a decorator for this. Instead, how about a higher-order generator that you pass a parser function to?

```
def parse_using(file_name, func):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield func(line)

def parse_foo_line(line):
    return 'This line is very foo-ey: ' + line

parsed_foo = parse_using('foo.txt', parse_foo_line)
parsed_bar = parse_using('bar.txt', parse_bar_line)  # etc...
```

Note these functions are generators, so they won't actually parse anything until they're iterated (and even then, they only return results once). If you want to eagerly parse things, cast to a list.

```
parsed_foo = list(parse_using('foo.txt', parse_foo_line))
```

Comment: Ok, but what about signature-changing decorators in general? Are they good? Are they bad?

Comment: In general, bad IMHO :)